# Symfony2 MVC and ExtJS4 MVC

Tags: extjs, symfony, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Could someone please explain to me the correct file structure of a Symfony2 MVC and ExtJS4 MVC project? (When used together!)

Comment: For Symfony2 you can take a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html as well as the quick tour: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ExtJS files should be placed in the Resource/public folder of your Bundle

```
YourBundle/
  Resources/
    public/
      images/
      css/
      js/
        extjs/
        app/
```

You can use the assets:install command-line command to install it in the web-folder afterwards. You can use Assetic thats included to the Symfony Standard Edition to take care of your JS-Files too.

Comment: Timo. What if couple of bundles are using extjs? Should I duplicate extjs files in Resource/public of all of this Bundles? Or is there better solution?

Comment: That depends on how your application works, while attempting to figure this out, I found that if you have multiple bundles all using the same extjs library the best approach IMHO would be to create another bundle that manages client side libraries and includes them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the heading "Root Tree Structure" of The [Definitive Guide to Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/02-Exploring-Symfony-s-Code) for the structure of an Symfony application. Quoting from the documentation:

> Only the files and scripts located
>   under the web root (the web/ directory
>   in a symfony project) are available
>   from the outside. The front controller
>   scripts, images, style sheets, and
>   JavaScript files are public. All the
>   other files must be outside the server
>   web root--that means they can be
>   anywhere else.

So, you should put you ExtJS code in the web/ directory. You can have a folder structure like this:

```
web/
  css/
  images/
  js/
    extjs/   --> ExtJs Library
    app/     --> ExtJs MVC application
  uploads/
```

The `app` folder will contain the ExtJS MVC structure. Refer to [MVC Architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture) guide for the folder structure of an ExtJS MVC application.

Comment: He specifically stated Symfony2 in the tags.

Comment: oops!! my mistake.. I don't think there is any change in how the ExtJS files are placed. So, the above configuration should work.

Comment: You shouldn't place your CSS/JS in the webfolder in Symfony2. Instead place it in your Bundle fodler and use assets:install or Assetic.